# 1.9.2.3 8788 Security Patch Issues

Tags: magento-1.9, security, supee-8788

I am having some issues with security patch `SUPEE-8788` ON Magento version 1.9.2.3 I have looked in the applied patches and it only lists 7405. So when I have ran 8788 v2 I came across some errors:

```
app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected! Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf.rej
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected! Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf.rej
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
Hunk #1 FAILED at 90.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css.rej
```

I have tried replacing the files with different version from Magento but that has not worked either.

Could anyone help with why the patch is failing?

Thanks

Comment: I have read that and tried zipping up the sh file that did not work. I have tried to manually replace the files and then run the patch and that also did not work

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just downloading the files from a fresh magento version and replaced the files. Seemed to solve my issue. As I have done a diff and there was no difference between the files.

So replacing it seemed to work.